# I keep getting Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript

Im trying to get a list but y keep getting this error when I call

```
this.users = this.userProvider.getAllUsers();
```

> [ts] Type 'void' is not assignable to type
>   'FirebaseListObservable'.

I tried everything, but I just can't make it work. It used to work before I added the ${nCompany} node. I really hope you can give me a hand!

Thanks!

users.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database'
import { UserProvider } from '../../providers/user/user-provider';
import { ChatViewPage } from '../chat-view/chat-view';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'users.html'
})
export class UsersPage {
    users:FirebaseListObservable<any>;
    uid:string;
    sPictureURL:string;

    constructor(public nav: NavController, public userProvider: UserProvider) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userProvider.getUid()
        .then(uid => {
            this.uid = uid;
            this.users = this.userProvider.getAllUsers();
        });
    };
```

user-provider.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

@Injectable()
export class UserProvider {
  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase, public local: Storage, private camera: Camera) { }

  // Get Current User's UID
  getUid() {
    return this.local.get('uid'); 
  }

  // Get Current Company
  getnCompany() {
    return this.local.get('nCompany'); 
  }  

  // Get Info of Single User
  getUser() {
    // Getting UID of Logged In User
    this.getUid().then(uid => {
      return this.db.object(`/users/${uid}`);
    });
  }


  // Get All Users of a company
  getAllUsers()  {
    this.getnCompany().then(nCompany => {
      return this.db.list(`/companies/${nCompany}/users`);
    });

  }
```

Comment: `getAllUsers` indeed returns `void`, or in other words doesn't return a value. You have no `return` in the body of the method. It looks like you have an async operation going on inside, and you cannot return a value from an async operation. You can return a `Promise` to a value, but not the value itself

Comment: As @NitzanTomer said, your method returns null. If it worked before `${nCompany}`, then it's that `${nCompany}` returns a bad value ! See in the chrome console, under `Network`, which endpoint is called

Comment: Hi. The nCompany works, I see it with console.log. Also I dont get what you said "You can return a Promise to a value, but not the value itself " and that I dont do return, its right here return this.db.list(`/companies/${nCompany}/users`);

Answer (score 0):

I dont get it, if I use

```
  // Get All Users of a company
  getAllUsers()  {
      return this.db.list('/companies/01/users');
```

works fine... May be Im just tired...